# VM scale set with custom image and in existing VNET/SUBNET?

Tags: arm

I am trying to deploy VM scale set with custom image and in existing VNET/SUBNET,unfortunately it could not run  can any help on this??

I have two templates:

1. templateone creates VMSS  with windows and Vnet with custom image.
2. templatetwo creates VMSS with linux and in existing VNET.

I tried to club template one to template two so that template three could create windows VMSS in existing vnett,unfortunately it could not run, any help?

```
      >>> "virtualMachineProfile": {
         "storageProfile": {
           "osDisk": {
             "name": "vmssosdisk",
             "caching": "ReadOnly",
               "createOption": "FromImage",
                "osType": "Windows",
                        "image": {
                        "uri": "[parameters('sourceImageVhdUri')]"
```

Below is the error message

```
              "target": "vmss.properties.osProfile",
             "message": "Could not find member 'osProfile' on object of type               
            'Properties'. Path 'properties.osProfile', line 1, position        
            "target": "vmss.properties.networkProfile",
         "message": "Could not find member 'networkProfile' on object of   

        'Properties'. Path 'properties.networkProfile', line 1, position   
        "code": "BadRequest",
         "message": "The request message is invalid.">
```

Comment: What is the link between your question and tag "arm" ?

Comment: I think you will have probably more answer with other tag like vmware or something more accurate with technologies you want to configure

Comment: @Garf365 Its an Azure ARM template i am working on ...